# Get 'Headers already sent' error for the plugin I am creating when I try to login

Tags: plugins, php, login, headers

I am trying to create my first plugin. So far it actually works fine but for one error:

I get a 'Headers Already Sent' PHP message when I try to login to wp-admin.

If I remove the plugin file from the wpcontent/plugins directory, login as usual, then replace the plugin file it works fine - this just seems to occur with login in and out.

My (abridged) code is:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Product Manager
Plugin URI: http://www.tech-knowledge.com.au
Description: Add, edit and remove products
Version: 1.0
Author: Me
Author URI: http://www.tech-knowledge.com.au
License: Restricted
*/

if ( is_admin() ){
/* Call the html code */
add_action('admin_menu', 'prodmanager_admin_menu');

function prodmanager_admin_menu() {
add_options_page('Product Manager', 'Product Manager', 'administrator',
'product-manager', 'prodmanager_html_page');
}
}

function prodmanager_html_page() {
?>

<div>

<h2>Product Manager</h2>
<!--usual HTML and PHP Code--> 
</div>
?>
```

Let me know if you would like to see it all.

Any advice would be really, really appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to WPSE.

Firstly you should do your conditional logic inside the action's callback, for example:

```
add_action( 'init', 'somefn' );
function somefn() {
    if( is_admin() ) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Secondly, you are hooking into `admin_menu` which is only run in the backend anyways, so the `is_admin()` check can be removed.

```
/* Call the html code */
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'prodmanager_admin_menu' );

function prodmanager_admin_menu() {
    add_options_page( 'Product Manager', 'Product Manager', 'administrator',
'product-manager', 'prodmanager_html_page' );
}

function prodmanager_html_page() {
?>

<div>
<h2>Product Manager</h2>
<!--usual HTML and PHP Code--> 
</div>

<?php }
```

And as Brian said, you have a closing PHP tag where it's not needed, and you aren't closing the last function with a `}`, I added it into the chunk of code above. I think that would pretty much solve your problem!

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong. You have a closing PHP tag where there is no opening PHP tag at the end of the script. This means you are creating output before the headers are being sent.

Change this:

```
function prodmanager_html_page() {
?>

<div>

<h2>Product Manager</h2>
<!--usual HTML and PHP Code--> 
</div>
?>
```

To this:

```
function prodmanager_html_page() {
    ?>
    <div>
        <h2>Product Manager</h2>
        <!--usual HTML and PHP Code--> 
        </div>
    <?php
}
```

You do not need a closing PHP tag at the end of your script. This is a good practice to help safeguard against stray whitespace after the closing tag which will give WP a white screen of death.

Comment: Thanks heaps guys. You are right. I have removed the ?> at the end of my script and it now works fine.

Comment: Make sure to accept the answer so others can tell what solved your issue.